# What is ChainId is not defined ? (OpenSea 2.0 clone using Next.js, Replit, thirdweb and tailwind Css)

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, metamask, replit, thirdweb

So there's this video on YouTube that I am following along for building an Open Sea 2.0 clone using
Next.js, Replit, thirdweb, Infura, & Tailwind CSS. The chain used in the video is Rinkeby Network and as rinkeby is not stable anymore I am using goerli. But my code is stuck at:

```
erver.browser.development.js:5898:11)
error - pages/_app.js (7:23) @ MyApp
ReferenceError: ChainId is not defined
   5 |   return( 
   6 |    <ThirdWebProvider>
>  7 |      desiredChainId = {ChainId.Goerli}
     |                       ^
   8 |      chainRPC{{
   9 |       [ChainId.Goerli]: 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/e5f83ad2d2814ff69492f524bd8a50a0'
  10 |    }}
```

Using replit as a sc editor. PS: I am a beginner so I decided to build through a follow along video.

Thanks!

I didn't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Where does `ChainId` come from? Where is it defined in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import ChainId from here:

`import { ThirdwebProvider, ChainId } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";`